# Is a Turing Machine able to reduce a grammar by chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: turing-machines, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

If given a grammar, for example, a **context-sensitive (type 1)** can it always be "reduced" to a **equivalent context-free grammar (type 2)** and so on for grammars type 2 to "reducing" and getting a type 3?

How can I **prove** or **show** that this is undecidable? (if this is the case)

I know that is undecidable whether a context-free grammar has a equivalent regular grammar. And so on for a sensitive-context having a equivalent context-free grammar, but don't know how to generalize it.

P.s.: When I say "reducing" I mean the lower level in Chomsky Hierarchy, considering type 0 the top and the lowest is the type 3.

Comment: No, it isn't.  There may or may not be a "reduced" grammar for the same language. If there isn't one, obviously no Turing machine can invent one. Wirse, it is not decidable whether an equivalent grammar exists.

Comment: For the other grammars, I mean, given a context-sesitive can I always get a equivalent context-free and so on for the other grammars? Where do I read about this undecidable problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you can't. Context-sensitive grammars produce a strictly larger set of languages. The undecidability proof is in Chomsky's original paper iirc, and it is certainly in Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation, by Hopcroft & Ullman.

Comment: A very similar question was recently asked and then deleted by Léo Eduardo Silva (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94030/can-a-grammar-always-be-reduced-by-chomsky-hierarchy). Are you the same person, or just taking the same class?

Comment: I don't know what was this question, can't see it: page not found. I don't know what his question is about. Did he get any answer? I'm curious.

Comment: I edited my question as I was instructed.

Comment: @reinierpost I've already seen that question, but it only concerns whether a context-free grammar describes a regular language. Maybe your answer is general, but I can't see it yet. What I am asking is more general: I want to know how can I show a grammar may not have a equivalent grammar in other Chomsky Hierarchy. I already searched stackexchange for equivalent questions, but I didn't succeed. Thank you, anyway!!

Comment: @archtes: No, that question is exactly your question. My answer says: if you have a CFG, you cannot in general determine whether it describes a regular language. This proves that even if your grammar is context-free you cannot in general decide where its language fits in the Chomsky hierarchy. Which implies that the answer to your more general question is: no, it cannot be done for arbitrary grammars, either. If you want to prove other cases than context-free to regular, [Greibach's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem) is useful.

Comment: There are languages in each of the tiers of the Chomsky hierarchy that can't be generated by grammars in lower levels. That is precisely it's point.